# MVC - pass ViewData as boolean

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When passing boolean value from controller to the view using ViewData, how do I retrieve it as a boolean value in javascript?
example:

**Controller:**

```
ViewData["login"] = true;
```

**View**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var login = <%= (bool)ViewData["Login"] %>;   /// this doesn't work, throw javascript error;
</script>
```

yeh surely i can do

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var login = '<%= ViewData["Login"] %>';   /// now login is a string 'True'
</script>
```

But i rather keep login object as a boolean rather a string if that's possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the single quotes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var login = <%= (bool)ViewData["Login"] ? "true" : "false" %>;
</script>
```

This will result in:

```
var login = true;
```

Which will be parsed as a boolean in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var login = new Boolean(<%= (bool)ViewData["Login"] ? "true" : "false" %>);
</script>
```

edit: actually the first way I had it wouldn't work. The true/false values passed to Boolean() must be lowercase for this to work.