# Repository bool to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have:
GuestResponseRepository, IRepository -> Interface, HomeController -> Controlle, Thanks -> View

The GuestReresponseRepository has a list with responses in it. When I add a response via a form the response is added to the list. When you try to add a response for the second time with the same values the AddReponse method returns false. I want to use the bool in my view to display a different text. How can I do this? Below my code

GuestResponseRepository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using PartyInvites.Abstract;

namespace PartyInvites.Models
{
public class GuestResponseRepository : IRepository

{
    private static List<GuestResponse> responses = new List<GuestResponse>();

    IEnumerable<GuestResponse> IRepository.GetAllResponses()
    {
        return responses;
    }

    bool IRepository.AddResponse(GuestResponse response)
    {
        if (responses.Any(x => x.Email == response.Email)) //here
        {
            if (responses.Any(x => x.WillAttend == response.WillAttend)) //here
            {
                return false;
            }

            var attend = responses.First(x => x.Email == response.Email && x.WillAttend != response.WillAttend);
            attend.WillAttend = response.WillAttend;
            return true;
        }

        responses.Add(response);
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

IRepository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PartyInvites.Models;

namespace PartyInvites.Abstract
   {
     public interface IRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<GuestResponse> GetAllResponses();
        bool AddResponse(GuestResponse response);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PartyInvites.Models;
using PartyInvites.Abstract;


namespace PartyInvites.Controllers {
public class HomeController : Controller {
    private IRepository repository;

    public HomeController(IRepository iRepository)
    {
        this.repository = iRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult Index() {

        return View(repository.GetAllResponses());
    }


    public ViewResult PartyPeople()
    {
        return View(repository.GetAllResponses());
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult RsvpForm() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult RsvpForm(GuestResponse guestResponse) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {

           repository.AddResponse(guestResponse);                
            return View("Thanks", guestResponse);
        }
        else
        {
            // there is a validation error
            return View();
        }
    }
}
}
```

view

```
@model PartyInvites.Models.GuestResponse

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Thanks";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1>Thank you, @Model.Name!</h1>
    <div class="lead">
        @if (Model.WillAttend == true) {
            @:It's great that you're coming. The drinks are already in the fridge!
        } else {
            @:Sorry to hear that you can't make it, but thanks for letting us know.
        }

        @if (bool from Addresponse is false) {
            @:<p>You already submitted this response. Are you sure this is right?</p>
        }

    </div>
    <a href="/Home/PartyPeople">Link naar pp</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I would recommend not using models as viewmodels. Your controller action (or better yet a service of some kind) should be constructing the viewmodel based on the model and the return of the repository. This way you can avoid using the ViewBag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC - pass ViewData as boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321694/mvc-pass-viewdata-as-boolean)

Comment: I agree with you. If I would have know how, I proberly would have done it your way. But this it what they teach me to do atm. So If you have some examples don't hesitate to share :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the return from AddResponses in a boolean variable and set a custom property in the [ViewBag object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
 bool result = repository.AddResponse(guestResponse);                
 ViewBag.Response = result;
 return View("Thanks", guestResponse);
```

Now in the `Thanks` view you can use this property to decide which text to write

```
@model PartyInvites.Models.GuestResponse
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Thanks";
   bool response = (ViewBag.Response != null ? Convert.ToBoolean(ViewBag.Response) : false);
 }

 .....

@if (!response) {
    @:<p>You already submitted this response. Are you sure this is right?</p>
}
```